# Drake Rigid_body_tree calculating the jacobian question

Tags: drake

I am currently trying to calculate the jacobian of a kuka arm using the "rigid_body_tree.cc" file for the equation: Tau = J^T*F, where Tau is the 7 joint torques of the kuka arm, F is the cartesian forces and torques at the end-effector, and J^T is the jacobian transposed.

There exists a function in drake called transformPointsJacobian which takes in a cache, points, from_body_or_frame_ind, to_body_or_frame_ind, and in_terms_of_qdot.

The function first calculates the geometric Jacobian which outputs a 6x7 matrix (kuka has 7 joints)

Then, it takes that matrix and uses it to determine a 3x7 jacobian which is calculated below:

`J.template block<kSpaceDimension, 1>(row_start, *it) = Jv.col(col);`

`J.template block<kSpaceDimension, 1>(row_start, *it).noalias() += Jomega.col(col).cross(points_base.col(i));`

This shrinks down the 6x7 geometric jacobian into a 3x7 jacobian where the first 3 rows were calculated by Jv + Jw*Transformation.

This code definitely works, but I don't seem to understand why this step works. Also, since I will need the torques in the cartesian end-effector space, I will need the full 6x7 jacobian.

In order to get the last 3 rows of the jacobian, how can I use the output of the geometric jacobian so that it will be valid in the equation, Tau = J^T*F?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider switching to the supported class MultibodyPlant rather than the soon-to-be-deprecated RigidBodyTree in the Drake attic. The Jacobian documentation is much better there -- the group of methods is [here](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#mbp_system_matrix_computations). An example (with lots of documentation) is [here](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a3d0b9504378cc8125d43aaedf342cf8e); that one produces the 6x7.

Is there a reason you need to use the old code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a deadline that I want to meet and I may not have time to change all my code to the newest version.

Comment: I looked inside multibody_tree.cc's CalcJacobianAngularVelocity. Inside this function, it calls CalcJacobianAngularAndOrTranslationalVelocityInWorld() 

At the end of this function, the final linear component of the jacobian is calculated by v + w*T :

Hv_PFpi_W = (Hv_PB_W + Hw_PB_W.colwise().cross(p_BoFp_W)) * Nplus;

Looking above a few lines, I found that the rotational section of the jacobian is calculated by :

Js_w_PB_W = Hw_PB_W * Nplus;

Ignoring Nplus, it seems that the rotational component is equal to the final jacobian's rotational component ().

Comment: However, when I tried implementing this in rigidbodytree by changing transformpointjacobian to return a 6x7 matrix, it didn't work. The arm moves in a random direction.

Comment: We also had trouble working with RigidBodyTree which is one of the reasons we replaced it with better-documented code. You might try asking one of the original authors for help -- you could check git blame. I think Twan Koolen may be the author of the code you are looking at.